# Difference between visual dimensions on QGraphicsScene and SVG file generated using QSvgGenerator

Tags: c++, qt, svg, qgraphicsscene, qtsvg

I specifically added scene rect to understand where the scene border is. The screenshot shows that the text “*Hello, World! This is a multiline text. 1111*” extends beyond the stage boundary.

[image]

For some reason, the entire text is displayed in the SVG file, although the second screen clearly shows that some text should not be displayed in the SVG at all. It is also clear that, for some reason, the stage border is larger.

[image]

Why is there such a visual difference?

```cpp
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QGraphicsTextItem>
#include <QFont>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QSvgGenerator>
#include <QFileDialog>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QVBoxLayout>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QGraphicsScene scene;
    scene.setSceneRect(0, 0, 400, 400); 
    QGraphicsView view(&scene);
    view.show();
scene.addRect(scene.sceneRect(), QPen(Qt::black));
    QString text = "Hello, World! This is a multiline text. 1111";
    QFont font("Arial", 16);
    QGraphicsTextItem *textItem = scene.addText(text, font);
    textItem->setPos(50, 50); 
    view.fitInView(scene.sceneRect(), Qt::KeepAspectRatio);    
    QPushButton generateButton("Generate SVG");
    QObject::connect(&generateButton, &QPushButton::clicked, [&]() {    
        QString filePath = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(nullptr, "Save SVG", "", "SVG files (*.svg)");
        if (filePath.isEmpty())
            return;
        QSvgGenerator svgGenerator;
        svgGenerator.setFileName(filePath);
        svgGenerator.setSize(QSize(400, 400)); 
        svgGenerator.setViewBox(QRect(0, 0, 400, 400));   
        QPainter painter;
        painter.begin(&svgGenerator);       
        QRectF sceneRect = scene.sceneRect();
        painter.drawRect(sceneRect);      
        scene.render(&painter);

        painter.end();
    });
    QWidget mainWindow;
    QVBoxLayout layout(&mainWindow);
    layout.addWidget(&view);
    layout.addWidget(&generateButton);
    mainWindow.setLayout(&layout);
    mainWindow.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

The SVG file generated exactly the same dimensions. I opened it in different browsers, they all display the same file. There is a suspicion that I missed some settings for the scene. I used different types of fonts, the problem was the same everywhere.

Comment: I don't think it has any effect. You can simply specify the direct path.  QString filePath = "C:/Users/1/Pictures/1.svg";

Comment: Sorry, I was in a hurry and misread the code, I stupidly thought you were checking if the file were not empty. In any case, I'm not able to reproduce the issue, what I see in the view is what I also see in different viewers from the svg file.

Comment: that is, what is visually the same in the program and in the browser? The words do not go beyond the rect limit? If so, what result did you get from the screen, top or bottom?

Comment: Well, not *exactly* the same, because there are some differences in how device pixel sizes are eventually rendered in Qt, how they are converted into svg commands and how are eventually shown in the svg viewer, but the text *is* truncated. Note that I tested this on PyQt5.15 (porting your code accordingly), but there shouldn't be any difference.